# Creating a factory that returns singletons

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton, factory

I have common code (multiple class that I call controllers) that needs to be shared by multiple packages in the project.
I was thinking of creating a factory, that returns these controllers. 
So, the factory would have a hashmap, that can return the controller asked for or create a new one if not created.
The controllers have common code and since I don't need to create multiple instances of these controller, I think they should be singletons.

Does this seem like a good approach?

Comment: This sounds like the kind of functionality an IOC container like Spring provides out of the box. Why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: Th reason could be to avoid doing service location which is usually an anti-pattern

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think what you need is a [Multiton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiton_pattern).

> The multiton pattern is a design pattern similar to the singleton,
>   which allows only one 
>   instance of a class to be created. The multiton pattern expands on the
>   singleton concept to manage a map of named instances as key-value
>   pairs. Rather than have a single instance per application (e.g. the
>   java.lang.Runtime object in the Java programming language) the
>   multiton pattern instead ensures a single instance per key.

```
public class FooMultiton {
    private static final Map<Object, FooMultiton> instances = new HashMap<Object, FooMultiton>();

    private FooMultiton() {
        // no explicit implementation
    }

    public static synchronized FooMultiton getInstance(Object key) {

        // Our "per key" singleton
        FooMultiton instance = instances.get(key);

        if (instance == null) {
            // Lazily create instance
            instance = new FooMultiton();

            // Add it to map   
            instances.put(key, instance);
        }

        return instance;
    }

    // other fields and methods ...
}
```

> The controllers have common code and since I don't need to create
>   multiple instances of these controller, I think they should be
>   singletons.

You need single instance *does not necessarily* mean that you need a *Singleton Pattern*. You can have a single instance and pass that on subsequent calls to that. Don't necessarily enforce singletonness using `private` constructor.

Also read [Evil Singletons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons?rq=1) for more on down points of Singletons. After reading that if you still feel you need Singleton then go with it.

Comment: This pattern is very similar to flyweight pattern, but in flyweight you have to ensure that the flyweights don't have internal state for proper use, the same as here.. Also it's not recommended to use an `Object` as a key in a hash "key-value collection" .!

Comment: @nachokk The program is not necessarily for great performance ;) Just to get the idea out. BTW it is from Wikipedia. But a good point though.

Comment: Not for performance, "All hash-based collections assume that an object’s hash value does not change while it is in use as a key in the collection. If a key’s hash code were to change while it was in a collection, some unpredictable and confusing consequences could follow".

Answer (score 2):

Yes it does. The Singleton design pattern suffer for several problems, one of which is that Singletons cannot be extended.

However, if you retrieve these controllers via a ControllerFactory.createControllerX() instead of ControllerX.getInstace(), you will be able to extended ControllerX in future and all its client will not be aware of using an extended version. Which is a really good thing

Comment: BTW, please have a look at my last post on my blog http://passionatesw.blogspot.co.uk/